# yii2 find with() - What is it for?

Tags: database, activerecord, yii2

Maybe this question is very simple but I couldn't understand what is **with()** in yii2 despite I've read couple of articles about it. What does this mean:

```
$players = PlayersModel::find()->with("countries")->all();
```

What is this for? In my database (tables are related) on what purpose can it be used:

[image]

Please show me useful aspect of this feature: `with()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`with()` is explained in the [Yii 2 Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#lazy-eager-loading).

This method allows to eagerly load the relational data in your query.

In your example there is `PlayersModel`. I assume there is also `ClubsModel` that represents data from database table `clubs`.

Let's say Player belongs to one of the Clubs. There should be defined relation between `PlayersModel` and `ClubsModel`. If it's defined in `PlayersModel` it could be something like:

```
public function getClub()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ClubsModel::className(), ['id' => 'id_club']);
}
```

So now there is relation named `club`. Each time you call `$model->club` (where `$model` is object of `PlayersModel`) you get related `ClubsModel` object.

Now - when you look for specific Player:

```
$player = PlayersModel::find()->where(['id' => $id])->one();
```

or (a bit simpler to write):

```
$player = PlayersModel::findOne($id);
```

This is one performed SQL query. In next step you want to get the Club of this Player - there is relation already defined so you can call:

```
$club = $player->club;
```

But this performes another SQL query - it's called **lazy loading**.

Let's say you know you need Player data together with his Club data at once - you can use `with()` to get this:

```
$player = PlayersModel::find()->where(['id' => $id])->with('club')->one();
```

It's one SQL query. Now when you call:

```
$club = $player->club;
```

There is no need for second query this time because this relational data is already fetched - it's called **eager loading**.